# Cocoa app plug-ins / sugars?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins

My app should be extendable using plug-ins or often called sugars.
I would place them under appname.app/Contents/sugars/sugarname.appnamesugar

Those are bundles, compiled in a separate project.
This would allow me to expand the functionality of the app without having to submit an update.

So, this is how much I know. How do I go on?
How do I launch any methods and get results from them my main application.
It would be good if I could give some kind of a class which they subclass and override it's methods to implement the functionality.

Those apps can do this:

http://panic.com/coda/

https://droplr.com/hello

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You are not allowed, and should not assume that you can add/remove stuff from your main bundle.

Comment: Yes, in Mac OS X you can. And even if not, I could save them in the application support folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of [the Cocoa code loading guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/LoadingBundles.html) for some information on how to use `NSBundle` to load plug-ins.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll read thought it and accept your answer when I find the answer.